# Why do Chabad-Lubavitch and Breslov seem to be the only Chassidish branches doing Kiruv?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, kiruv-outreach

Kiruv is a worldwide movement at this point and that outreach covers various streams of Orthodox Jewish life. Chabad is probably the most famous in this kind of outreach but there is also Breslov outreach and Modern Orthodox outreach unrelated to either.

My question is simple. **Why does it seem like only Chabad-Lubavitch and Breslov are the only active Chassidic movements doing Jewish outreach?**

Other Chassidic movements don't seem that interested in outreach. The Satmar aren't standing on street corners asking people "are you Jewish?" and offering tefillin.

Is there a specific reason for why this is?

Comment: They're just more well-known. There are pockets of other chassidus that have people engaging in Kiruv e.g. - https://mishpacha.com/learning-curve-on-kiruv/

Comment: The Bostoner Chassidus is also known to be active in Kiruv circles

Comment: Belz also has a whole kiruv infra-structure - https://mishpacha.com/born-to-lead/

Comment: The Hidabroot TV channel in israel is an initiative of Belz , they also run seminars and have a bal teshuva yeshiva in israel https://worldofbelz.org/outreach/ that said Chabad is different in that it's a central theme of their group.

Comment: Can't the answer be that they prioritize other things?

Comment: Chassidus generally responded to the Enlightenment by closing itself off from the outside world. That obviously would make it hard to do kiruv.

Comment: _Other Chassidic movements don't seem that interested in outreach. The Satmar aren't standing on street corners asking people "are you Jewish?" and offering tefillin._ this was an innovation of the 7th Chabad Rebbe, and was very unique. There is a big idea behind it that characterised a lot of his innovations. You can find lots of information about that philosophy on chabad.org

Comment: I would also like to point out something that everyone SHOULD know, but hardly anyone does: the modern kiruv movement was started by Chabad, specifically the 7th Rebbe (to much push back and criticism, I might add).